# whats wrong in my version of caesar cipher? pset 2

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

The Caesar cypher encrypts text with user derfined key and text.

In cryptography, a Caesar cipher, also known as Caesar's cipher, the shift cipher, Caesar's code or Caesar shift, is one of the simplest and most widely known encryption techniques. It is a type of substitution cipher in which each letter in the plaintext is replaced by a letter some fixed number of positions down the alphabet. For example, with a left shift of 3, D would be replaced by A, E would become B, and so on. The method is named after Julius Caesar, who used it in his private correspondence

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main ( int argc , string argv[] )
{    
  int key,save;
  string s ;

  key = atoi(argv[1]);    
  s = GetString();

  if (  argc != 2 )
  {
    printf("prgram is yelling at you !!");
    return 1 ;
  }

  for ( int i = 0  ; s[i]!='\0' ; ++i)  // manipulation without storing character
  {
    if ( isalpha( s[i]) )           // checks whether input is in character set or not
    {
      if ( islower ( s[i] ) )       // FOR LOWER CASES
      {
        save = key % 24 ;
        s[i] = s[i] + save ;

        if ( s[i] > 'z' )
          s[i] = 'a' + ( s[i] - 'z' -1 );
      }

      if ( isupper ( s[i] ) )        // FOR UPPER CASES
      {
        save = key  % 24 ;
        s[i] =  s[i] + save ;

        if ( s[i] > 'Z' )
          s[i] = 'A' + ( s[i] - 'Z' -1 );
      }
    }

    printf ( "%c" , s[i] );
  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

**Facts:**

```
:) caesar.c exists 
:) caesar.c compiles
:( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 a s key
   \ expected output, but not "b" 
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
   \ expected output, but not "yxc"
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
   \ expected output, but not "EDUIRR"
   :( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
      \ expected output, but not "FeVJss"
   :( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
        \ expected output, but not "srw"
   :( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using   12 as key
       \ expected output, but not "adxp, em tqxxa!"

   :( handles lack of argv[1]
        \ expected output, not standard error of \      "/opt/sandbox50/bin/run.sh: line 31: 189..."
```

Comment: To start with: the formatting of your program is wrong, your program is unreadable.

Comment: I formatted the code for you to some readable format.

Comment: This looks like copy paste of question on some test server.. anyway - nice introduction but no real question, maybe you are still thinking about the question :D

Comment: why do you use string as argv? use standard char **argv or so.. also nitice that in the first line the server flagged the a->b wrong but you did printfd b.. maybe you are missing \n ..

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. This will indicate to the community that  you found a solution and will give some reputation to you and the answerer.

Comment: Note that the original (circa 1AD) Latin alphabet had 24 characters (no J, no U), but the modern Latin alphabet has 26, so using '% 24' is going to give problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a `char` type to store the intermediate calculation which are too big for that type, instead of a larger type. This calculation:

```
s[i] = s[i] + save ;
```

the addition will be done in type `int` due to integer promotions, but then it will be assigned back to type `char`, the result will be implementation defined. It will probably wrap-around and give the invalid value.

To solve this use `int` to store results that

```
int temp = s[i] + save;
if ( temp > 'z' )
    temp = 'a' + ( temp - 'z' -1 );   
s[i] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small Caesar cipher routine in Swift using Xcode playground take a look at it, hope it helps:

```
            import UIKit

            let letters:[String] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

            var message: String = "HERE GOES THE TEXT THAT YOU WANT TO ENCRYPT"

            func encryptMessage(message: String, shift: Int) -> String {
                var count = 0
                var letterIndex = 0
                var encryptedMessage = ""
                for i in message.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").characters {
                    letterIndex = letters.indexOf(String(i))! + shift
                    if letterIndex >= 26 {
                        letterIndex = letterIndex - 26
                    }
                    count = count + 1
                    encryptedMessage += letters[letterIndex]
                }
                return encryptedMessage
            }

            func decryptMessage(message: String, shift: Int) -> String {
                var count = 0
                var letterIndex = 0
                var decryptedMessage = ""
                for i in message.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").characters {
                    letterIndex = letters.indexOf(String(i))! - shift
                    if letterIndex < 0 {
                        letterIndex = 26 + letterIndex
                    }
                    count = count + 1
                    decryptedMessage += letters[letterIndex]
                }
                return decryptedMessage
            }
            // Encrypt Message By Shifting 5 positions to the right in the alphabet letters array (A becomes F, B becomes G...)
            print(encryptMessage(message,shift: 5))
            // Decrypt Message By Shifting 5 positions to the left in the alphabet letters array (F becomes A, G becomes B...)
            print(decryptMessage(encryptMessage(message,shift: 5),shift: 5))
```